# Initializing a big record takes around 20 mins when stepping with F10 in debug mode

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

I have modified an old cobol program and encountered some strange behaviour/feature while testing it with debug. There is a rather big record structure and an initialize to go along with it.

While debugging, if i step to the initialize line with f10 it takes around 20 minutes to complete the step. However, if i place a breakpoint before and after it and resume over it with f12 it completes in a fraction of a second.
note:this code was already in the program

Is it a bug or a feature that i should be aware?

```
01  TABLE.                          
    03 RECORD                   OCCURS 999. 
       05 LINE                  OCCURS 150. 
          07 FIELD              PIC X(03).


INITIALIZE                  TABLE.
```

Comment: this is certainly a bug, but without knowing exactly which debugger you are using, its hard to help.

Comment: It's the default ile debugger on ibm i 7.2(STRDBG)

Comment: When INITIALIZE is applied to a group item it is equivalent to doing a MOVE to each elementary item under the group. In this case you are doing the equivalent of 'MOVE SPACE TO FIELD (X,Y)' 149,850 times. Still 20 minutes is a lot of time to complete this task.

Comment: As @SaggingRufus said, this is most likely linked to the debugger rather than the code itself. Millions of such instructions (Move Spaces to Field) can generally be executed in less than a second on mainframe, as you may have noted.

Answer (score 0):

use the redefine "table-1 redefines table pic x(149850)". Initialize table-1. More efficent. Debugger is highlighting inefficency. Doing something 150000 times along with initializing "field". Runtime program may also be taking long exec. In my experience this may show an exponential rise in exec time as volume from small to large repeations. If you double the "occurs"  you will most likely see exec time in hours. Similar to use of a search key vs index on a database.